# Tomcat CORS problem, how to solve 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing

Tags: tomcat, cors

I tried to develop Angular2 application, and Im stuck, that console in firefox write to me header  CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing. I try to add this header in my controller, but without success. package org.heller.contacts.resources;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.heller.contacts.dto.ContactDto;
import org.heller.contacts.service.ContactService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("contacts")
public class ContactResource {
    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<List<ContactDto>> getContacts() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200/public/contacts");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().headers(headers).body(contactService.getAll());
    }

}
```

I also tried to add this into my web.xml, but with still same error:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>180</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Can someone give me a poit, hot to solve this issue. Im completely stuck with it. I try to solve it for one day, but Im still on the begining. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add this filter to my app and Cors are running:
package org.heller.filter;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("here");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        System.out.println("here2");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.heller.filter.SimpleCorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```